# How do I use '~' (tilde) in the context of paths?

Tags: python, path, expanduser

To fix a problem in code for work, I was told to "use a path relative to ~". What does `~` mean in a file path? How can I make a path that is relative to `~`, and use that path to open files in Python?

Comment: I can think of two perfectly correct but completely different answers to this, depending on what you are doing your web application development **with**. Indeed, the completely different answers so far given cover those, but nobody can be sure which is right, or if it isn't a third one. Please edit your question to include the technology used.

Comment: You fixed the problem ~ it would have been nice if you had posted some sample code

Answer (score 47, accepted):

it is your `$HOME` var in UNIX, which usually is `/home/username`.

"Your home" meaning the home of the user who's executing a command like `cd ~/MyDocuments/` is `cd /home/user_executing_cd_commnd/MyDocuments`

Comment: `~` points to your `$HOME`, which can be any directory (i.e., not necessarily `/home/username`).

Answer (score 20):

Unless you're writing a shell script or using some other language that knows to substitute the value of `$HOME` for `~`, tildes in file paths have no special meaning and will be treated as any other non-special character.

If you are writing a shell script, shells don't interpret tildes unless they occur as the first character in an argument.  In other words, `~/file` will become `/path/to/users/home/directory/file`, but `./~/file` will be interpreted literally (i.e., "a file called `file` in a subdirectory of `.` called `~`").

Used in URLs, interpretation of the tilde as a shorthand for a user's home directory (e.g., `http://www.foo.org/~bob`) is a convention borrowed from Unix.  Implementation is entirely server-specific, so you'd need to check the documentation for your web server to see if it has any special meaning.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using pathlib for filenames then you can use on both Windows and Linux (I came here for a windows answer):

```py
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('~').expanduser()
print(p)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487827/why-am-i-forced-to-os-path-expanduser-in-python for why this is necessary.