# os.chdir() in os module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, directory, operating-system

If you use **macOS** then you would know how you can type **`cd ~/Documents`** in the **terminal** and **regardless of the user of the computer**, the **CWD would change to Documents**.

In python, I'm trying to do the same thing using **`os.chdir("~/Documents")`** using the **os module** but it **doesn't work**!

Does anyone know another way to do this?

Comment: Hey Zooby, I'm asking how to get the currently active user's home directory's Documents dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How do I use '~' (tilde) in the context of paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488603/how-do-i-use-tilde-in-the-context-of-paths)

One solution to your problem based on the above description would be `os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents'))`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was so stumped on this one!

Comment: I think tilde is a special character in google, so you normally benefit from using the word not the character when searching. Happy to help :)

Comment: Unrelated to the question or the answer, but relevant to @Zooby's comment, [tilde is not a special character in google search](https://www.searchenginewatch.com/2013/06/25/google-kills-tilde-search-operator/)

Comment: Then why does "How to use tilde in python" and "How to use ~ in python" return vastly different results?